# How calculate distance between nearest point in one layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

I have points from polyline. I need to calculate distance between point to nearest pont. For example.  i have ponts with id 1-5 a need to calclulate distance between  1-2  2-3  3-4 4-5   because i need information about distance between point 5 and point 1. But not straight distance , i need curved distance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with linear referencing.  Use the Create Route tool to convert the lines into routes.  Make an ID field identical to the ObjectID if you have no existing unique ID for the lines.  To preserve the line direction, calculate a field for the From Distance that is 0 and a field for the To distance which is the line length, then use the Two Fields method.

Then you can use the Locate Features Along Route tool to convert the points into an event table that will find the point measure along the line, which will be the same as the distance along the line.  The points should have an ID value for the line they are associated with so that you can eliminate point duplications on adjoining lines and sort the point events by line ID and then by measure.

I do not know if you need any of the distances between the intermediate points or not, since they are unnecessary to get the distance along the line between point 1 and 5.  The distance along the line between any two pairs of points along the same route can be calculated by just subtracting the smaller measure from the larger measure without having to chain any intermediate points together.

If all distances are relative to the point before, you can sort the event table on the Route ID and measures and add a field to the table that holds the ObjectID value -1.  Then duplicate the table, join the table on the original ObjectID to the duplicate table on the field you calculated equal to the ObjectID-1, select the set of records where the RouteID is the same in both tables, and you can calculate the distance from the original point to the next point by subtracting the original measure from the joined measure.  These events can now create the line segments between the two points if you want.

Anyway, Linear Referencing handles every aspect of your problem and does much more than you have thought of.